# Cabal build with c2hs not finding .chs module

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, c2hs

I am trying out c2hs, and wanted to compile a small example of a shared library with Cabal to get started.

I have the following relevant section of the cabal file `test.cabal`:

```
executable libtest.so
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Dummy.hs
  other-extensions:    ForeignFunctionInterface
  build-depends:       base
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -no-hs-main -threaded
  build-tools:         c2hs
```

Then the source. `src/Dummy.hs`:

```
import Test

main :: IO ()
main = return
```

In the file `src/Test.chs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

module Android where
```

And then when I try to compile (`cabal configure && cabal build -v`) I get the following error message:

```
Component build order: executable 'libtest.so'
creating dist/build
creating dist/build/autogen
Building test-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'libtest.so' for test-0.1.0.0...
Building executable libtest.so...
creating dist/build/libtest.so
creating dist/build/libtest.so/libtest.so-tmp
/opt/ghc/bin/ghc --make -no-link -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -j8 -static
-outputdir dist/build/libtest.so/libtest.so-tmp -odir dist/build
/libtest.so/libtest.so-tmp -hidir dist/build/libtest.so/libtest.so-tmp-stubdir
dist/build/libtest.so/libtest.so-tmp -i -idist/build/libtest.so/libtest.so-tmp
-isrc -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen
-Idist/build/libtest.so/libtest.so-tmp
-optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -hide-all-packages
-package-db dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id
base-4.7.0.1-1a55ebc8256b39ccbff004d48b3eb834 -XHaskell2010
src/Dummy.hs -no-hs-main -threaded

src/Dummy.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module ‘Test’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Please, can you tell me what the cause of the error is? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Test to the other-modules field.

Comment: But isn't that for exporting the module as if it was a library?

Comment: No, it's for telling Cabal about modules which it's not necessarily able to figure out for itself (which can happen for many valid reasons... not worth diving into here). In this case, Cabal needs to know that it needs to generate the .hs file for GHC.